# Wizard with extended lifespan, name starts with N and translates as “no-one”

Tags: story-identification

Looking for the name of a series of books about a wizard who makes a pledge to the gods and in return is granted extended lifespan (there are 3 booming thunder sounds to signify acceptance of his pledge).

His name starts with N and a reoccurring theme is a pun that his name translates to "no one".

Comment: Is the name *Nemo* (*nobody* in Latin)? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo#Fiction) turns up the *[Orphans of Chaos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphans_of_Chaos)* trilogy, but the plot doesn't seem to match.

Comment: This is a combination of two fairly common tropes in mythology, so it wouldn't surprise me if there's a lot of stories described by this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Katherine Kerr's [Deverry series](http://www.deverry.com/) has Nevyn (which means "no-one"; not his original name, but the one used throughout the books) as the central character. His deal isn't with gods as such (lords of Dweomer), but it is recognised by the three knocks.

I believe [Daggerspell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0006482244) is the book where Nevyn's story is introduced. His lifespan is extended until he is able to fulfil the pledge he made, which ends up being a long time. The core of the books is that people reincarnate, so he is able to fulfil the pledge with reincarnations of the people from his original time.